# Adjusting tick settings on Seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been trying to adjust the tick settings for a heat map through several different methods with no success. The only method that actually changes the settings of the plot is `plt.xticks(np.arange(217, 8850, 85))` but even when using several different intervals for this method the data is skewed greatly to the right.

When the tick labels aren't clumped together (for example using `plt.xticks(np.arange(217, 8850, 500))`) the last tick mark on the end of the axis is no where near the 8850 max I need to show all the data.

I'm trying to adjust these tick settings on both the x and y in order to view the full range of data (Xmax: 8848 Xmin: 7200, Ymax: 8848 Ymin:217) with intervals that allow the tick labels to be readable.

Images of Heatmap:

First image is with `plt.xticks(np.arange(217, 8850, 500))`:

[image]

Second image is with `plt.xticks(np.arange(217, 8850, 85))`:

[image]

Third is original Heatmap:

[image]

```
 color = 'seismic'
 success_rate = (m['Ascents'] / ((m['Ascents']) + (m['Failed_Attempts'])))*100
 success_rate.fillna(0).astype(float)
 mm['success_rate'] = success_rate
 mm['success_rate'].round(2)
 vm = mm.pivot("Height(m)", "Prominence(m)", "success_rate")
 cPreference = sns.heatmap(vm, vmax = 100, cmap = color, cbar_kws= {'label': 'Success Rate of Climbs (%)'})
 cPreference = cPreference.invert_yaxis()


 """Methods I've Tried"""
 plt.xticks(np.arange(217, 8850, 1000)) """<< Only line that actually makes visible changes but data is skewed greatly"""

 cPreference.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(mm["Height(m)"].min(), mm["Height(m)"].max(), (mm["Height(m)"].max() - \
 mm["Height(m)"].min()) / 10))
 cPreference.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(mm["Prominence(m)"].min(), mm["Prominence(m)"].max(), (mm["Prominence(m)"].max() \
 - mm["Prominence(m)"].min()) / 10))

 sns.set_style("ticks", {"xtick.major.size" : 8, "ytick.major.size" : 8})

 plt.title("What is a good Mountain to Climb?")
 sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: Would you please add an image of the result you are getting?

Comment: Just uploaded them! @ViníciusAguiar

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
cPreference = sns.heatmap(vm, vmax = 100, cmap = color,
    xticklabels = 10, yticklabels = 5,
    cbar_kws={'label': 'Success Rate of Climbs (%)'})
```

By setting `xticklabels` or `yticklabels` equal to an integer, it will still plot the same column, but it will only display every nth item in that column.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the behavior of the tick positioning manually by setting a custom tick locator, for example

```
from matplotlib import ticker
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tick_locator)
```

here is the [link](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) to the documentation for the many options